# Как узнать все недостающие зависимости для maven проекта (для работы в частной сегменте)

Tags: java, maven

Пытаюсь собрать maven проект в частном сегменте сети. Выхода на maven central нет. Так уж случилось, что нету никаких прокси и зеркал а ля нексус, откуда можно было бы стащить зависимости. В итоге после каждой команды mvn package приходится докидывать по одной зависимости (через почту запароленным архивом). И так уже полдня. Есть ли какой способ узнать все недостающие зависимости, чтобы отправить их пачкой?
`mvn dependency: tree -Dverbose` не помогает, т.к. опять же не хватает какой-то зависимости, чтобы построить дерево.
`mvn help: effective-pom` тоже не строится.
`mvn dependency: resolve` так же выдает только одну недостающую зависимость. Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в мавене, но разве есть смысл в такой постройке дерева? Ведь, например, недостающие зависимости могут быть транзитивными, и вы никогда не сможете понять заранее, подтянуться ли они к проекту, когда вы подключите прямые зависимости, или нет.

Comment: Не знаток Maven, но не вижу другого способа, как в ручном режиме. То есть, например берём [jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.3) и тянем дополнительно [jackson-annotations](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.3) и [jackson-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.3). И так далее, рекурсивно тянем зависимости зависимостей... Либо тянуть зависимости на машине с доступом к Maven и переносить локальный репозиторий .m2